# Specific string values in TypeScript based on an object

Tags: typescript

How can I require a parameter to be a specific string value in TypeScript?

For example:

```
const obj = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3,
};

interface Props {
  x: Object.keys(obj); // instead of 'a' | 'b' | 'c'
}

const foo = (x: Props) => console.log(x);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `typeof` operator to first get the type of `obj` and then the `keyof` operator to get the keys of the object (`"a" | "b" | "c"`).

```js
const obj = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3
};

interface Props {
  x: keyof typeof obj;
}

const foo = (x: Props) => console.log(x);
```

[TypeScript Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYewdgzgLgBCBGArGBeGBvAsAKBjAhgFwwCMANDnvMQEwW4zDEDMOAvgNw44CWYUAUwBOAM3zABMAApCQABwgZKMAB7EA1gICeIETCha5A3XCRdsbbtlCRYIkCFQwAFGumyFASlQA+RuAgQABsBADogkABzV09zIA)